# Im trying to compare 2 strings and it's returning true even when false

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

if (values[i][0] = values[x][0] && x != i )

I and X are both row numbers and 0 just points it to column A. The code under this runs every time. I'm running it on the sheet called "Games W20"

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H2C7oRFZZRCKRyQ-rn6MFpB5rCAraCq-V2Z4-YIrD2Q/edit#gid=1657776731

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Your sample spreadsheet is view-only and does not allow copying, therefore the script therein is inaccessible. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You should add a second = for comparison

```
if (values[i][0] == values[x][0] && x !== i )
```

`

Comment: Doc ref - [Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#comparison_operators)